# Playframework async cache can't found existing class

Tags: java, playframework

In my application that based on play framework in service class, I used play async cache. Play cache internally use ehcahe. When I try to get value from cache program flow freeze in this step. When I try to execute this code from debugger (Idea Evaluate Expression tool)

```
private final AsyncCacheApi cacheApi;
...
cacheApi.getOrElseUpdate("123", () -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(123));
```

I get an error

```
Compilation failed: 
package com.typesafe.config does not exist 
package org.keycloak does not exist
```

cacheApi passed into Servce class by guice.

Service class was loaded from an external jar as external dependencies.

Why play cache don't see classes? How to fix it?

Everything work without using cacheApi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine after the following instruction
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaCache#Setting-the-execution-context

> By default, all Caffeine and EhCache operations are blocking, and async implementations will block threads in the default execution context.
>   Usually this is okay if you are using Play’s default configuration, which only stores elements in memory since reads should be relatively fast.
>   However, depending on how cache was configured, this blocking I/O might be too costly.
>   For such a case you can configure a different Akka dispatcher and set it via 
>   play.cache.dispatcher so the cache plugin makes use of it:

```
play.cache.dispatcher = "contexts.blockingCacheDispatcher"

contexts {
  blockingCacheDispatcher {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-factor = 3.0
    }
  }
``
```